# Directx-11 Two vertex buffers and two input slots

Tags: c++, directx-11, vertex-buffer

I have a problem with setting two separate vertex buffers (and input slots). One buffer must contain vertices, the second buffer - color data. I have found this problem here:
[Direct3D multiple vertex buffers, non interleaved elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248727/direct3d-multiple-vertex-buffers-non-interleaved-elements)
So i followed this instructions but got error message box:

Error Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Calling: md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd2, &initData2, &mBoxVB2)

Here's the code:

```
//layout array   
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc3[] =
{
{"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"COLOR",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};

D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
mTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
HR(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc3, 2, passDesc.pIAInputSignature, 
    passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &mInputLayout));

// buffers
ID3D11Buffer* mBoxVB;
ID3D11Buffer* mBoxVB2;
ID3D11Buffer* buffers[2];
buffers[0] = mBoxVB;
buffers[1] = mBoxVB2;


XMFLOAT3 vertex[] =
{
XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f)  ,
XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f)  ,
XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f)  ,  
XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f)  , 
XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f)  ,
XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f)  , 
XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f)  , 
XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f)  
};

// vertex buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT3) * 8;
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
vinitData.pSysMem = vertex;
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mBoxVB));

XMFLOAT4 color[] =
{
 (const float*)&Colors::White  ,
 (const float*)&Colors::Black  ,
 (const float*)&Colors::Red    ,  
 (const float*)&Colors::Green  , 
 (const float*)&Colors::Blue   ,
 (const float*)&Colors::Yellow , 
 (const float*)&Colors::Cyan   , 
 (const float*)&Colors::Magenta 
};

// where the namespace Colors is defined like
namespace Colors
{
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 White     = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Black     = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Red       = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Green     = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Blue      = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Yellow    = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Cyan      = {0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    XMGLOBALCONST XMVECTORF32 Magenta   = {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}; 
};

// color buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd2;
vbd2.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd2.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4) * 8;
vbd2.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd2.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd2.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd2.StructureByteStride = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData2;
initData2.pSysMem = color;
// here is our problem:
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd2, &initData2, &mBoxVB2));

// inside DrawScene():
UINT stride[] = {sizeof(XMFLOAT3), sizeof(XMFLOAT4)};
UINT offset[] = {0,0};
md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, buffers, stride, offset);
md3dImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(mBoxIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);


// and the shaders
cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj; 
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL  : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH  : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;

    vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);

    vout.Color = vin.Color;

    return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{

    return pin.Color;
}

technique11 ColorTech
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader(  ps_5_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
BuildFX():

```
DWORD shaderFlags = 0;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG;
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif

    ID3D10Blob* compiledShader = 0;
    ID3D10Blob* compilationMsgs = 0;
    HRESULT hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"FX/color.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_5_0", shaderFlags, 
        0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMsgs, 0);

    // compilationMsgs can store errors or warnings.
    if( compilationMsgs != 0 )
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, (char*)compilationMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        ReleaseCOM(compilationMsgs);
    }

    // Even if there are no compilationMsgs, check to make sure there were no other errors.
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        DXTrace(__FILE__, (DWORD)__LINE__, hr, L"D3DX11CompileFromFile", true);
    }

    HR(D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(), 
        0, md3dDevice, &mFX));

    // Done with compiled shader.
    ReleaseCOM(compiledShader);

    mTech    = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
    mfxWorldViewProj = mFX->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();
```

Comment: You should take a moment to read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).

Comment: Maybe it's too late but I didn't see you use the mInputLayout you created. It should be bind to the context with vertex buffers.

Answer (score 0):

vbd2 is uninitialised.

You've copy/pasted the code from above and not changed vbd to vbd2.

Comment: Thx, you are right - I corrected the code but now I got no errors and no cube on the screen :(

Comment: Have you tried a) Turning on DX11 Debug Layer? b) Using Visual Studio's Graphics Debugger?

Comment: I'm using VS2010, windows 7, and there is no file D3D11SDKLayers.dll on my system. But simple debug layer is working - macro HR().

Comment: I mean program is compiling now, but in window i got rendered correctly background only.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with function BuildFX(), I pasted the code above, and i think somewhere i miss sth...

Comment: The D3D11SDK Debug Layer is available for Windows 7. See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx). I'd strongly suggest moving to VS 2013 or VS 2015--Community edition is free if you quality for the license and includes the graphics debugger; avoid the Express for Windows desktop SKUs